# C function to compare last elements of a string to another using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

My problem is to see if `str1` ends with the contents of `str2`.

I tried this:

```
int string_ends_with(const char *str1, const char *str2) {
    int len;
    len = strlen(str2);

    while ((*str1 == '\0' - len) && *str1 != '\0') {
        if (strcmp(str1, str2) == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char str[10] = "banana";
    char str1[5] = "ana";

    string_ends_with(str, str1);

    return 0;
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

This problem needs to be solved only using pointers.

Comment: What do you mean by "solved only using pointers"?

Comment: This question is from an old exam and it says "can use only the notation of pointers, without using the notation of arrays".

Comment: `*str1 == '\0' - len` don't know what you meant, but looks very fishy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This condition in the while statement

```
while((*str1 == '\0' - len) && *str1 != '\0')
```

does not make sense. What does `'\0' - len` mean ?

You could write the function the following way

```
int string_ends_with(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    size_t n1 = strlen( str1 );
    size_t n2 = strlen( str2 );

    return n2 <= n1 && strcmp( str1 + n1 - n2, str2 ) == 0;
}
```

If you may not use standard functions then you can write the function the following way

```
int string_ends_with(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    const char *p1 = str1;
    const char *p2 = str2;

    while ( *p1 ) ++p1;
    while ( *p2 ) ++p2;

    while ( p1 != str1 && p2 != str2 && *p1 == *p2 ) --p1, --p2;

    return  p2 == str2 && *p1 == *p2;
}
```

Comment: That was an attempt to only compare the last elements of str1 by subtracting the end with the lenght of str2

Comment: Very elegant implementation!

Comment: @JoséSalgado Yes this compares the tail of str1 with str2.

Comment: @gollum i agree. i also like the 2nd version. running to the end of both strings and then decrement the pointers again in a loop to check if the characters are the same.

Comment: Small and elegant! but both can be improved slightly.  The first could use `return n2 <= n1 && memcmp( str1 + n1 - n2, str2, n2 + 1 ) == 0;` since you don't need to retest for string termination at this stage, and the second could use fewer tests with `for (;;) { if (p2 == str2) return 1; if (p1 == str1 || *--p1 != *--p2) return 0; }`

Comment: @chqrlie You need to check the terminating zero because the second string can be empty.

Comment: Yes of course, but all cases are covered: there are exactly `n2 + 1` bytes to compare at `p1` and `p2`, including the `'\0'`.  `memcmp` should be faster than `strcmp` for this.

Answer (score 0):

This will be useful if you want to know which string has a greater/lesser value.

```
int string_ends_with(char *p1, char *p2)
{
    char    *q1;
    char    *q2;

    if (! p1 || ! p2)
        return something;

    (p1 + (strlen(p1) - 1));
    (p2 + (strlen(p2) - 1));

    while (q1 >= p1 && q2 >= p2) {
       if (*q2 < *q1) return -1;
       else if (*q2 > *q1) return 1;

       q1--; q2--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Of course do basic error checking, i'd presume that's a given for most and prefer not to clutter my meagre offering with un-necessary code with regards to a simple example. Still, don't want to ruffle any feathers.

Alright.

Comment: In case of empty strings the function has undefined behaviour.

Comment: The function shall return a value. You may not use a return statement without a value.

Comment: you just messed up your assignment for `*q1`and `*q2`with your error checking :)

Comment: @Nunchy I like your approach with return something.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow but `something` is undefined. He'd have to do `int something = WHATEVER;`

Comment: The function fails if `p1` is shorter than `p2`, it is not supposed to return EQUAL.  The arguments should be `const char *`.  The return value is meaningless as -1=LESS and 1=GREATER, just make it 1=YES or 0=NO.

Comment: @Nunchy By the way you could write the function much simpler:   int string_ends_with(char *p1, char *p2) { return something; }

Comment: I'm not intending to work on the finer details for anyone and trust the OP capable enough to do error checking and define whatever values they want to return. that wasn't really the point...the point. but par for the course here on SO...sorry for participating.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow here i was waiting for you to `#define` `WHATEVER`
Also in your "shorter" version for this function. If you intend to define `something` through a macro, i'd write it all caps `return SOMETHING;`

Answer (score 0):

You initial test is incorrect, as noted in the other answers.

Here is a slightly smaller and potentially more efficient version:

```
int string_ends_with(const char *str1, const char *str2) {
    const char *p1 = str1;
    const char *p2 = str2;

    while (*p1) p1++;  // same as p1 += strlen(p1);
    while (*p2) p2++;  // same as p2 += strlen(p2);

    while (p2 != str2) {
        if (p1 == str1 || *--p1 != *--p2)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Note that your `main` test function should output something and perform more tests:

```
void test(const char *a, const char *b) {
    printf("\"%s\" ends with \"%s\": %s\n", 
           a, b, string_ends_with(a, b) ? "yes" : "no");
}

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "banana";
    char str1[] = "ana";

    test(str, str1);
    test(str1, str);
    test(str, str);
    test(str, "");
    test("", str);
    test("", "");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i rly liked the `while ( *p1 ) ++p1;` from Vlad.   
you say your version is petentially more efficient.   
but isn't `strlen()` doing somewhat the same (run through the string with a loop and incrementing) but has to calculate the length in addition? (i assume by subtracting the pointer on the start from the pointer that ran to the end)
But your while loop might be in fact more efficient.

Comment: OK, `strlen` is inlined by `gcc` and `clang`, so it generates better code than the `while (*p1) p1++;` loop, but I will write the loops to remove this ambiguity.  The last loop is more efficient than Vlad's (and he will not like it ;-)

Comment: i thought that might be the case with `strlen()` but thx for the confirmation. wouldnt it be easy to optimize Vlads loop?
`while ( p1 != str1 && p2 != str2 && *p1 == *p2 ) --p1, --p2;`   
`while ( p1 == str1 || p2 == str2 || *p1 != *p2 ) --p1, --p2;`
But since i am way to tired now and cant check if i made any mistakes with boolean algebra, and the optimization from the compiler would possible allready do that...

Comment: @Flikk: I'm afraid I can confirm you are too tired right now.  Your proposed alternative does not work, even if optimized by the compiler.  I should get some sleep too.

Comment: yeah, that would be for the better. just editing my comment to say that i am stupid and it wont work. good night edit: cant edit it anymore ...

Comment: good morning .... now i know what i was trying to do ... but do not know why... i wanted to change the while loop into a "until" loop ... like:
`while(1) {if (p1 == str1 || p2 == str2 || *p1 != *p2) break;}`

Comment: @Flikk: this is more or less what I do, but I separate the tests to avoid having to re-test to determine the return value. I had an intermediary version like this: `for (;;) { if (p2 == str2) return 1; if (p1 == str1 || *--p1 != *--p2) return 0; }`.